Alternative for void pointers in modern C++
I want to retreive data from a source, made available through one function, by a set of different functions. I come from c, so I have this example:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getInt(void *v, const double &src) {*static_cast<int*>(v) = src; }
void getDouble(void *v, const double &src) {*static_cast<double*>(v) = src; }

struct twoInt{int a; int b;};
void getTwoInt(void *v, const double &src)
{
    static_cast<twoInt*>(v)->a = src;
    static_cast<twoInt*>(v)->b = static_cast<int>(src*10) % 10;
}

template <typename T>
void getData(T f, void* val)
{
    double dataSource = 2.1;
    f(val, dataSource);
}


int main()
{
    int valI;
    double valD;
    twoInt valTwoInt;

    getData(getInt, static_cast<void*>(&valI));
    cout << "Int: " << valI << endl;

    getData(getDouble, static_cast<void*>(&valD));
    cout << "Double: " << valD << endl;

    getData(getTwoInt, static_cast<void*>(&valTwoInt));
    cout << "Int1: " << valTwoInt.a << ", Int2: " << valTwoInt.b <<endl;
}

But I would like to do it in a modern C++ way, and without the void pointers, to have more type safety.

std::any perhaps?

No type erasure: template or std::variant and with type erasure std::function and lastly std::any...

void getInt(void *, const double &) can simply be void getInt(int &out, double src).

void get(int& result, double value) { result = value; }? Or a little more complex template<typename T> void get(T& result, double value) { result = value; } It's even possible to use templates for both the result and the value. And for custom types (structure/classes), you could create a suitable operator= overload.

Actually, I would do just plain and simple template<typename T1, typename T2> assign(T1& result, T2 const& value) { result = value; }, and then make sure there's an overloaded operator= function when needed (optionally specialize the assign function).

You don't need type erasure here, so correct type and template do the job:
void getInt(int& out, double src) { out = src; }
void getDouble(double& out, double src) { out = src; }

struct twoInt{int a; int b;};
void getTwoInt(twoInt& v, double src)
{
    v.a = src;
    v.b = static_cast<int>(src * 10) % 10;
}

template <typename F, typename T>
void getData(F f, T& val)
{
    double dataSource = 2.1;
    f(val, dataSource);
}

int main()
{
    int valI;
    getData(getInt, valI);
    std::cout << "Int: " << valI << std::endl;

    double valD;
    getData(getDouble, valD);
    std::cout << "Double: " << valD << std::endl;

    twoInt valTwoInt;
    getData(getTwoInt, valTwoInt);
    std::cout << "Int1: " << valTwoInt.a << ", Int2: " << valTwoInt.b <<std::endl;
}

Demo

This looks straight forward. I probably should learn more about templates. So far, I always avoided them.

At this point, the output parameters should also be removed and replaced by return values in the respective functions.

@Bert: Possibly, but don't want to go too far: we then have identity function which can just be removed. A function wrapper which can be removed too, and have a constexpr constant instead...

@Jarod42 Yeah, it was more a comment to the person who asked the question. I just wanted to point out that the design as is can still be improved more. :)

@Bert: I agree, using the return value would make it more readable.
